# AWS IAM role chaining doesn't grant the policy from the child role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have a policy called `FooPol` that attached to the user as the policy shown below,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/fooRole",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `fooRole` attached to a policy called `BarPol` as the policy shown below,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/barRole",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

the `barRole` itself can perform `cloudformation:DescribeStacks`. Somehow the access to perform `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` is denied for role `fooRole`, but it does authorized when I attach the `BarPol` directly to the user. why is that?

Comment: you are assuming a role, not adding additional permission to your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. When a user assumes a role, the user loses all of its permissions and inherits only the permissions that the assumed role has.